# Can this proof be done in $3-4$ lines? Or did I miss anything?

Tags: real-analysis

It's a very popular theorem that,

" A bounded sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent iff $\limsup x_n=\liminf x_n.$"

The definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence that I am using are as follows:

> If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in real number, then we define $\limsup x_n $ as the greatest subsequential limit of $(x_n)$ and $\liminf x_n$ is similarly the least subsequential limit of $(x_n).$

> Note: The word subseqntial limit is used to refer  to a limit of an arbitrary subsequence of the given sequence.
>
> If $(x_n)$ is unbounded above then we define, $\limsup x_n=\infty$ and if it's unbounded below then, we define $\liminf x_n=-\infty.$

Strangely, I found a two pages proof of this! I feel it can be done in 3-4 lines.

Here is my approach:

If $(x_n)$ is convergent, then all the subsequences converges to the same limit and hence, $\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n$ immediately follows.

Conversely if $x_n$ is such that $\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n$ then, let us conisder an arbitrary subequence $(x_{n_k})$ that is convergent. Now, $\lim x_{n_k}=l$(say) then, $l\leq \limsup x_n$ and $l\geq \liminf x_n$ and it follows that, $l=\limsup x_n=\liminf x_n$. Again, since $x_{n_k}$ is an arbitrary sub sequence so, we have that every convergent subsequence converges at the same point. So, $ (x_n)$ converges at $\limsup x_n=\liminf x_n.$ This completes the proof.

Now, I am interested to know is my approach correct? Did I miss something while proving it. It might be erroneous, I don't know,  but if it is, please do let me know.

Comment: The lower and upper sequences $\underline{x}_n = \inf_{k \geq n} x_k, \overline{x}_n = \sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ need not be subsequences of $x_n$

Comment: @athalhaids I think it doesn't matter,  any subsequences that is convergent works, imho.

Comment: But it does matter; if $\underline{x}_n$ is not a subsequence of $x_n$, you cannot use the reasoning that "all subsequences converges to $\lim x_n$ and so must the sequence $\underline{x}_n$".

Comment: @athalhaids Can you please clarify what do you mean by lower and upper sequences ?

Comment: How are you defining $\lim\inf x_n$? Is it not the limit of the sequence $\underline{x}_n = \inf_{k \geq n} x_k$? $\underline{x}_n$ is what I am informally calling "lower sequence" and it need not be a subsequence of $x_n$ itself

Comment: @athalhaids To be precise, my definition of $\liminf$ of a sequence is, the least limitpoint of a subsequence out of all the limit points of the other  convergent subsequences of the sequence. My definition says $\liminf$ should be a limit of the subsequence of the given sequence.

Comment: Then you should make it clear that you are using a different definition of $\lim\inf$ because the one I used is the standard one. They are equivalent of course. Also, your second part has issues. You have not shown that $x_n$ converges to begin with. You just showed **if it converges**, it converges to the common value of $\lim\inf x_n$ and $\lim\sup x_n$

Comment: @athalhaids I showed that all the subsequences of a given sequence converges to the same limit point. Doesn't that directly imply that $(x_n)$ is a convergent one as well and converges very well at the same point, as the other subsequences ? I read about it as a standard lemma, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No you showed all subsequences **that are convergent** converges to the same limit point.

Comment: @athalhaids And you mean, that it doesn't necessarily imply  that $(x_n)$ will be convergent as well , if all convergent subsequences of $(x_n)$ converges to the same limit point ? Do I have to show that all the subsequences should be convergent as well and myst converge to the same limit point as the convergent ones to claim $(x_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: Unless that is a result you can cite or reprove (which will make your proof longer), no. Also such a result is doubtful because there are trivial examples like $x_n = n$ that have no convergent subsequences to begin with so they vacuously satisfy the condition "all convergent subsequences converge to the same limit". Of course, such examples can be dismissed in this case because $\lim\inf x_n, \lim\sup x_n$ exist but regardless, a rigorous proof taking care of all these subtle issues would be longer

Comment: @athalhaids That was helpful. I suggest you adding your comment as an answer. I will be glad to accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: The result you are using is correct: if a sequence is *bounded* and all convergent subsequences converge to the same value, then the sequence converges. However you should prove it if you have not seen it before

Comment: @Keplerto Any way I can prove it?

Comment: I think it is necessary to prove it by contradiction: suppose $(x_n)$ does not converge. Then there is a neighborhood of $l$, outside of which lie infinitely many points of the sequence, and the contradiction follows easily

Comment: @Keplerto But where is the contradiction? It might be the case, that a particular neighbourhood of $l$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence and also, there are infinitely many terms of the sequence, outside that particular neighborhood (of $l$) at the same time.

Comment: Yes, but those infinitely many terms outside the neighborhood make a subsequence

Comment: @Keplerto Ah, so there we are and that subsequence converges to $l$ as well, but that's a contradiction. So, the sequence must converge to $l$. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: Yes, with one subtlety: if $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence with $|x_{n_k}-l| \ge \epsilon$ for all $k$, then it does not necessarily converge, but because it's bounded it has a subsequence that converges, and that's the one you must use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a critique of your attempt as requested. The first part of your proof is fine given the slightly altered (but equivalent) definition $\lim\inf x_n, \lim\sup x_n$ that you are using.

However, the second part has some steps missing. You did not show that $x_n$ converges to begin with. Rather, you showed that if a subsequence is **already known to be convergent**, its limit must be the common value of $\lim\inf x_n = \lim\sup x_n$. This is not quite enough to conclude that $x_n$ itself the converges. There are trivial non-convergent examples like $x_n=n$ that have no convergent subsequences to begin with so they vacuously satisfy the condition "all convergent subsequences converge to the same limit". Of course, the issue with such examples can be dismissed in this case because $\lim\inf x_n = \lim\sup x_n$ exist (which crucially implies that $x_n$ is **bounded**) but the proof needs to be expanded to address these subtler issues.